# Globally disable GRPC context cancelation

Tags: grpc-java

In our GRPC server we often use the GRPC FutureStub to call other GRPC servers asynchronously and we often don't mind if this RPC finishes after the current RPC.

Currently, we are forced to fork the context every time, otherwise our code will cancel the outgoing RPC aggressively, which causes problems.

Unfortunately, it is extremely easy to forget to do this and we have had multiple incidents in production because of this.

This feature is causing more issues/incidents and we'd like to disable it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable Context cancellation entirely. But you can avoid the gRPC server from influencing the clients.

You can use a server interceptor to fork all RPCs:

```java
public class ForkContextInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  @Override
  public <ReqT,RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT,RespT> call, Metadata headers,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT,RespT> next) {
    return Contexts.interceptCall(
        Context.current().fork(), call, headers, next);
  }
}
```